# Reset this with new object

Tags: c#, .net

In the below code, I would like to use the code in static load method to refresh the object...  but how would I reset the current object with new object ?  Is copying field by field is the only way ?

```
class WIP
{
    //  <Snipped> Various other properties...
    public Boolean Refresh()
    {
        //  Need to change the current object with the updated object
        this = WIP.Load(this.ObjectID);  // Says this is readonly...
        return true;
    }

    public static WIP Load(long ObjectID)
    {
        //  This static method fetches the data from DB and returns the object.
    }
}
```

**Edit :  I just got this idea after posting the question... Are there any traps in this ?**

```
class WIP
{
    //  <Snipped> Various other properties... 
    public Boolean Refresh()
    {
        //  This method fetches the data from DB and updates the object. 
    }

    public static WIP Load(long ObjectID)
    {
        WIP newObject = new WIP();
        newObject.ObjectID = ObjectID;
        newObject.Refresh();
        return newObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be confusing since "Load" of the object would delegate the load to the refresh method of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The closest you can come is basically to copy every member - which isn't going to work if some are read-only, of course.

Either you're trying to make your object immutable - in which case it *shouldn't* change under the feet of code which already has a reference to your object - or you're not, in which case you just need to make it *fully* mutable (ideally in some atomic fashion if there are multiple threads involved).

Comment: @The King: It's not clear what you're updated code is trying to do, given that the Refresh method is now completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need "WIP factory":

```
class WIP
{
    private static Dictionary<long, WIP> instances = new Dictionary<long, WIP>();
    private WIP()
    {
        ...
    }


    //  <Snipped> Various other properties... 
    public Boolean Refresh()
    {
        //  This method fetches the data from DB and updates the object. 
    }

    public static WIP Load(long ObjectID)
    {
        WIP wip = null;
        if (instances.ContainsKey(ObjectID))
        {
            wip = instances[ObjectID];
        }
        else
        {
            wip = new WIP();
            wip.ObjectID = ObjectID;
            instances.Add(ObjectID, wip);
        }
        wip.Refresh();

        return wip;
    }
}
```

This will cause that the only way to get instance of WIP is through the static "Load" method, and you will be using the same instance for every ObjectID unlike your current code that let anyone create new instance for the same ID.

This way calling the Refresh will update all the instances, no matter where they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Just think that every other object that holds a reference to the object that you're trying to "refresh" should be updated. You're only chance is to add an indirection level or to change your software's design.

Answer (score 0):

The `Static` method indicates that it is kind of a "Factory-Style" implementation. Hence should be used to create or get new instances of objects.

The `Refresh` method on the other side would naturaly be used to just refresh the properties on the current object and leaving the objects reference intact.

Usage:

```
// Initialize the object
WIP myWip = WIP.Load(1);
Console.WriteLine(myWip.ObjectId);
// Refresh the object from underlying data store
myWip.Refresh();


//  <Snipped> Various other properties... 
public Boolean Refresh() 
{ 
    //Read the values from data store and refresh the properties...        
    return true; 
} 

public static WIP Load(long ObjectID) 
{ 
    //  This static method fetches the data from DB and returns the object. 
}
```

For the Lifecycle-Management of objects I'd use some Factories. You might take a look at the factory pattern -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern.

Comment: Thanks... I have just updated the question before seeing your answer... Are you trying to say the samething as me..

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `this` keyword in a static method. Hence you can't use instance variables either.